# Do you know why my image buttons are not showing correctly in Android Studio?

Tags: android, image, button, maps

What I want to do is to display a button over my map. The idea is to touch the button and display to more buttons which are also images. 
For some reason the images do not appear in the way they should. Apart from this, when the app initializes you can see the three buttons. This should not happen as I want them to appear after I press in one of them

This is what is happening right now:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/0iHZ0] (sorry for bad quality)

Code

```
    public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener {

        private GoogleMap mMap;
        LocationManager locationManager;
        String provider;
        LatLng myPosition;

        TextView climaText;
        ImageButton reportes;
        ImageButton playas;
        ImageButton res;
        boolean reportesState = false;



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

            climaText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.climaText);

            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
            Location locationActual = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            Double lat = locationActual.getLatitude();
            Double lng = locationActual.getLongitude();
            downloadTask getData = new downloadTask();
            getData.execute("//http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="+String.valueOf(lat)+"&lon="+String.valueOf(lng)+"&appid=4ec901292084195e70a7a39b5259cf17");


           /* locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
            //locationRequest.setInterval(7500);
            //locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
            locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);*/

            //Si no inicializo aca, debo ponerle final dentro del metodo a cada boton
            reportes = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.reporte);
            playas = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.reportePlayas);
            res = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.reporteRes);

            // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        Location locationActual = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);;
        if(locationActual != null) {
            // Getting latitude of the current location
            double latitude = locationActual.getLatitude();
            // Getting longitude of the current location
            double longitude = locationActual.getLongitude();
            // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
            myPosition = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myPosition));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myPosition, 16));
            }
        }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.i("TESTTAG", "onLocationChanged called");
        LatLng currentPosition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(currentPosition));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentPosition, 16));
    }



    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);

    }


    /*
    public void obtenerClima(){

        CityAsyncTask task = new CityAsyncTask();
        task.execute("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk");

    }*/

    public void startDialogReportePlayas(View view) {
        AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this);
        View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_playas,null);
        mBuilder.setView(mView);
        AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
        dialog.show();

    }

    public void startDialogReporteRes(View view) {
        AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this);
        View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_restaurantes,null);
        mBuilder.setView(mView);
        AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
        dialog.show();

    }


    public void buttonClickAppear(View view){
        if(!reportesState) {
            playas.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            res.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            reportesState = true;
        }else{
            playas.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            res.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            reportesState = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/fab_margin">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        tools:context="com.naluapp.naluapp.MapsActivity"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/reporte" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/climaText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:text="Hola mundo" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/reporte"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="buttonAppear"
        android:onClick="buttonClickAppear"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/mapslocicon64pxl" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/reporteRes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/reportePlayas"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/reportePlayas"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:contentDescription=""
        android:onClick="startDialogReporteRes"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/mapslocicon64pxl" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/reportePlayas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/reporte"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/reporte"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:contentDescription=""
        android:onClick="startDialogReportePlayas"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/mapslocicon64pxl" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: See my post it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Inthis case you should have to use 
bringToFront, when call `bringToFront()` on the view is get in top(front)

```
yourView.bringToFront();
```

For example

```
reportes.bringToFront();

playas.bringToFront();

res.bringToFront();
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try this !!

Comment: I put that on the onCreate method of my map class but nothing happend. Do I need to do something else apart from that?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was found by changing srCompat to just src.